# Combinatorics, choosing 3 elements from 100

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we pick three different numbers out of the group $1,2,3,\dots,100$ such that the largest number is larger than the product of the two smaller ones? (The order in which we pick the numbers does not matter.)

Comment: First choose the two smaller numbers $x1,x2$ so that their product is less than 100. Then add $(100-x_1 \cdot x_2)$ to your running total. i.e. $$\sum _{x_i,x_j \ : \ x_i,x_j <100,\ x_i \cdot x_j <100} 100-(x_i \cdot x_j)$$ This can be computed relatively easily  by conditioning on $x_i's$ value.

Comment: In how many ways can we pick three different numbers out of the group


                                                     1,2,3,...,100

such that the largest number is larger than the product of the two smaller ones? (The order in which we pick the numbers does not matter.)
Please answer without any computer programming or algorithms. Pure math only

Comment: Have you seen how your second paragraph looks ?

Comment: It is indeed a math problem, but counting the solutions by hand will not teach me anything.  Perhaps if you shared the motivation for this problem it would be of greater interest to Readers.  This is one way of adding *context* to your bare problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we need $1\le a< b$ and $ab < c \le 100$

So $b < \frac ca \le \frac {100}a$ so $a < \frac {100}a$ and

$a^2 < 100$ so $a < 10$.

And $ab < 100$ so $ab \le 99$ so $b \le \frac{99}a$ so $b \le \lfloor \frac {99}a \rfloor$.

And $b+1 \le c \le 100$.

So the number or ways are:

So solution is $\sum_{a=1}^9(\sum_{b=a+1}^{\lfloor \frac {99}a\rfloor}(\sum_{c=ab+1}^{100} 1))=$.

$\sum_{a=1}^9(\sum_{b=a+1}^{\lfloor \frac {99}a\rfloor}[100-ab])$

$\sum_{b=2}^{99}(100-b) + \sum_{b=3}^{49}(100-2b) + \sum_{b=4}^{33}(100-3b) + \sum_{b=5}^{24}(100-4b)+ \sum_{b=6}^{19}(100-5b) + \sum_{b=7}^{16}(100-6b) + \sum_{b=8}^{14}(100-7b) + \sum_{b=9}^{12}(100-8b) + \sum_{b=10}^{11}(100-9b)=$

$\sum_{k=1}^{98}k + \sum_{k=2;+2}^{94}k + \sum_{k=1;+3}^{88}k + \sum_{k=4;+4}^{80}k+ \sum_{k=5;+5}^{70}k + \sum_{k=4;+6}^{58}k + \sum_{k=2;+7}^{44}k + \sum_{k=4;+8}^{28}k + \sum_{k=1;+9}^{10}k=$

$\sum_{k=1}^{98}k + \sum_{k=1}^{47}2k + \sum_{k=0;}^{29}(3k+1) + \sum_{k=1}^{20}4k+ \sum_{k=1}^{14}5k + \sum_{k=0}^{9}6k+4 + \sum_{k=0}^{7}7k+2 + \sum_{0}^{3}8k+4 + \sum_{k=0}^{1}9k+1=$

$\frac{98*99}2 + 2*\frac{47*48}2 + 3\frac{29*30}2 +30 + 4*\frac{20*21}2+ 5\frac{14*15}2+ 6\frac{9*10}2+4*10 + 7*\frac{7*8}2+ 2*8+ 8\frac{3*4}2+4*4 +9*\frac {1*2}2+2*1=$

$49*99 + 47*48 + 3*29*15 + 30 + 2*20*21 + 5*7*15 + 3*9*5 + 40 + 7*7*4+16 +4*3*4+16 +9 + 2=$

$49*99 + 47*48 + 29*45 + 30 + 20*42 + 35*15 + 27*5 +  40 + 49*4 + 32+48+11=10269$

Answer (score 0):

The [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20max%28100-i*j%2C0%29%2C%20j%3Di%2B1..99%2C%20i%3D1..98) is simply given by selecting all the numbers greater than their product:
$$
s=\sum_{i=1}^{98}\sum_{j=i+1}^{99} \max(100-ij,0) = 21320
$$