# Combinatorics, choosing 3 elements from 100, such that largest bigger than the product

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we pick three different numbers out of the group

```
                                                 1,2,3,...,100
```

such that the largest number is larger than the product of the two smaller ones? (The order in which we pick the numbers does not matter.)
Please answer without any computer programming or algorithms. Pure math only

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Why are you posting this question twice? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3397865/combinatorics-choosing-3-elements-from-100